# V-model and TinyMCE doesn't work together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, axios

I'm trying to get Vuejs and TinyMCE to work together.
I use @tinymce/tinymce-vue package which is the vue integration for TinyMCE.
I had followed all the instructions and everything seems to work, I mean I can write properly, insert image... everything except the v-model part.

Here is the simplified template :

```
<form action="/http://localhost:4000/articles" method="POST">

   <input id="data_title" class="input-title" v-model="title" type="text"/>

   <editor id="editor" v-model="content"></editor>

   <textarea id="data_description" v-model="description" class="input-resume"></textarea>
</form>
```

Script part :

```
 export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: "",
            description: "",
            content:"",
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#editor',
            plugins: "image",
            toolbar: [
                'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image',
                'alignleft aligncenter alignright'
            ]
        });
    }
```

I send my data to a Rest API using axios :

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:4000/articles', {
                title: this.title,
                description: this.description,
                content: this.content,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
```

Everything is ok, no errors. After posting the article, I have a title and a description, but no content. V-model doesn't seem to be bounded to the `<editor></editor>`, because in the chrome devtool nothing is happening when I'm writing in it. The others v-model in the form are perfectly working.

Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time fellows :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I came up with this solution :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea.tinymce',
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
            editor.getElement().dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the TinyMCE `init()` call in your `mounted()` code?  The TinyMCE wrapper does that for you and you can pass the init parameter to include the configuration you want.

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue#configuring-the-editor

I suspect your `mounted()` code is initializing TinyMCE and your Vue model data knows nothing of that - when the wrapper later tries to initialize the editor it fails because its already initialized which leads to the data binding not being in place.

Comment: I use this in the mounted because I use TinyMCE several time, and if I don't do that after navigating between the pages TinyMCE doesn't work properly! Thanks for you reply

Comment: The wrapper should handle all of that for you ... its designed to add and remove the editor as needed.

Comment: I just tried without it, it still doesn't work... :/

Comment: Perhaps the component is being cached?  Look at the `:key` option and how it can force a component to be re-rendered when you return to the page.  If the DOM items underneath TinyMCE are removed it will break TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but for those experiencing this issue, try wrapping your editor component tags in a div block like this:

```
<form action="/http://localhost:4000/articles" method="POST">

   <input id="data_title" class="input-title" v-model="title" type="text"/>

   <div>
       <editor id="editor" v-model="content"></editor>
   </div>

   <textarea id="data_description" v-model="description" class="input-resume"></textarea>
</form>
```

This worked for me and I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution.
If you are using vue-tinymce-editor

From TinymceVue.vue (in \node_modules\vue-tinymce-editor\src\components\TinymceVue.vue) remove this code:

```
        value : function (newValue){
            if(!this.isTyping){
                if(this.editor !== null)
                    this.editor.setContent(newValue);
                else
                    this.content = newValue;
            }
        },
```

And you don't need to init in mounted()

TinyMCE for Vue is bugged so much sometimes we have to find solutions in sourcefiles :P

Comment: I edited few other lines too: 
`content : '',` to `content : this.value,`

And from mounted I removed:
`this.content = this.value;`

Comment: any better solution to this without editing the source files

Comment: @Kamil Never ever edit dependency files. It is useless because of many reasons, one of them is it is excluded from the repo.

Comment: Never adjust code in packages. Changes will be overwritten on updates.